# Looking up a row in a dataframe from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames *df* and *ctr*.

- df contains a column *position* a value between 1 and 100, and a column *Average monthly searches* which contains an integer.

  ```
  position | Average monthly searches
         1 |                      250
         2 |                       10
         3 |                       30
         2 |                       40
         4 |                      100
  ```
- ctr contains a column *position* a value between 1 and 100, and a column *Decay Ctr* which is a percentage that reflects the decay at each position.

  ```
  Position | Decay Ctr
         1 |    27.18%
         2 |    18.27%
         3 |    12.66%
         4 |     9.13%
         5 |     6.90%
  ```

What I want to do is for each row in *df* lookup that position in *ctr* and times *Average monthly searches* by the correct *Decay Ctr*.

```
with open("C:\Environments\ENV\Export npower Report Rebuild KWs.csv",newline='') as csvfile:
    with open("C:\Environments\ENV\ctr_csv.csv", newline='') as ctrfile:
        ctr = pd.read_csv(ctrfile)
        df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
```

But I am unsure how to extract the correct elements to put it into a new column *visibility* in *df*. I tried using an `apply` statement but was unsure how to reference *ctr* correctly.

```
df['visibility'] = df.apply(numpy.multiply(df['Average monthly searches'] , ctr[ctr[]]   ), axis = 0 )
```

Comment: Are the positions in both same?

Comment: It is unclear how the `with()` blocks relate to your lookup attempt.

Comment: Please accept the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of what you are asking but if I understand it correctly, what you want to do it actually merge the two data frames and then you can perform whatever operations you like

**First way**

```
df1 = pd.merge(df,ctr, on='Position' index=False)
#Then you can multiply both columns however you like
df1['Visibility'] = df1.apply(numpy.multiply(df['Average monthly searches'] , df['Decay Ctr']), axis=1)
```

**Second Way**

```
  df1 = pd.merge(df,ctr,on='Position',index=False)

    def multiply(x):
       for index, row in df1.iterrows():
       row['Visibility'] = row['Average monthly searches'] * row['Decay Ctr']
       return row['Visibility'] 

df1 =df1.apply(multiply, axis=1)
```

Comment: `pd.merge` will do that for you

Comment: I am trying to lookup a position in ctr for each position in df e.g. if we look at the first row of df position is 1, so I would lookup position 1 in ctr and multiply Average monthly searches by that in this case (250 * 0.2718) –

Comment: That is the same thing the above code does. `pd.merge` will take intersection of both the data frames which in simple term means it will combine the frames with common elements on *Position* column that is what `on='Position'` is for

Answer (score 0):

You can just merge the two frames and then create a new column.

```
comb_df = df.merge(ctr, left_on = 'Position', right_on = 'Position')
comb_df['visibility'] = comb_df['Avg Monthly searches'] * 
comb_df['Decay']
```